# Why crystal violet inhibits growth of gram positive bacteria?

Tags: microbiology

In microbiology lab, we use MacConkey agar to selectively grow Gram-Negative bacilli. Crystal violet is used as a component of MacConkey agar for inhibiting growth of Gram Positive bacteria.

However I can't associate this action of crystal violet on Gram positive bacteria specifically. What is the probable mechanism?